# Add N hours to MySQL datetime representation

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add N more hours to MySQL datetime representation? For example
Current: 2013-12-01 19:30:13 (or I can get it with date("Y-m-d H:i:s") in PHP)

How can I get this: 2013-12-01 22:30:13 (adding 3 more hours)?

date("Y-m-d H:i:s") + 3 isn't working in PHP

Answer (score 1):

in PHP:

```
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours');
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use [date_add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

**From the docs:**

> DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit)
>
> These functions perform date arithmetic. The date argument specifies
>   the starting date or datetime value. expr is an expression specifying
>   the interval value to be added or subtracted from the starting date.
>   expr is a string; it may start with a “-” for negative intervals. unit
>   is a keyword indicating the units in which the expression should be
>   interpreted.
>
> The INTERVAL keyword and the unit specifier are not case sensitive.

For your case you can do:

```
date_add(now(), interval 3 HOUR)
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/26237)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you want to do it.

**in mysql**

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 3 HOUR

SELECT CAST('2013-12-01 23:49:09' AS DATETIME) + INTERVAL 3 HOUR
```

**in php**

```
Date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time() + 3600 * 3)
```